# Javascript error 'Object doesn't support this property or method' on document.getElementByID?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer-8, master-pages

I am attempting to run this JS function when a user clicks on a Panel (in a TableCell). This Panel is an element in a Content Page, which is used with the Master Page which has a Content Place Holder. When I try to click on the panel, the following error is thrown:

Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Here is the relevant code for the Master page ASPX:

```
       <link rel="Stylesheet" href="../includes/styles.css" />
       <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
           function swapDirections(control) {
               var main = document.getElementByID('ct100_TableContent_' + control);
               var long = document.getElementById('ct100_TableContent_' + control + '_long');
               var short = document.getElementById('ct100_TableContent_' + control + '_short');

               var mainhtml = main.innerHTML;
               var longhtml = long.innerHTML;
               var shorthtml = short.innerHTML;

               if (mainhtml.length == shorthtml.length)
                   main.innerHTML = longhtml;
               else
                   main.innerHTML = shorthtml;
           }
        </script>
```

Here is the relevant code for the Content page:

```
            Panel rigDirections = new Panel();
            rigDirections.CssClass = "clip";
            rigDirections.ID = u.Id.ToString() + "_RD";
            string MainDivRD = rigDirections.ClientID;
            Literal rigDir = new Literal();
            string sshort = "";
            if (u.RigDirections.ToLower().Length > (textCutOFF + 4))
            {
                sshort = Server.HtmlEncode(u.RigDirections.ToLower().Substring(0, textCutOFF).Trim()) + " ...";
                rigDir.Text = "<a class=RD_RA title=\"Click to Expand\" href=\"javascript: swapDirections('" + MainDivRD + "')\">" + sshort + "</a>"; ;
            }
            else
            {
                sshort = Server.HtmlEncode(u.RigDirections.ToLower().Trim());
                rigDir.Text = sshort ;
            }
            string slong = Server.HtmlEncode(u.RigDirections.ToLower().Trim());

            rigDirections.Controls.Add(rigDir);
            cell.Controls.Add(rigDirections);
```

And the Content Page ASPX:

```
      <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TableContent" Runat="Server">

       <asp:Panel ID="pnlTable" Width="950" runat="server">

       </asp:Panel>
      </asp:Content>
```

The error is being thrown on the first line of the function.

I have exhausted my internet searching skills, and I have never used JS before, so if anyone has any ideas I would greatly appreciate them.

Thanks!

badPanda

Comment: What type of element is `var main = document.getElementByID('ct100_TableContent_' + control);`?

Comment: Wow thats embarrassing! Thanks guys.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

javascript is case sensitive. `document.getElementByID()` is not a function, but `document.getElementById()` is.

Answer (score 6):

Capitalization matters.

```
document.getElementByID() //wrong
document.getElementById() //right
```

Answer (score 4):

It should be document.getElementById not document.getElementByID.

Answer (score 3):

javascript is case sensitive. try document.getElementById instead of document.getElementByID

Answer (score 0):

You should change getElementID to getElementById.  I did this too and couldn't figure it out for days.  Just remember that JavaScript is Case Sensitive and uses lowercase CamelCase.

Comment: I think you misspelled `getElementById` in both cases. Also this answer has already been provided.